# Looking for parents of Gustav Tesche (born 1877 Germany)

Tags: 19th-century, germany, brandenburg

I am looking for the parents (German or other) ancestors of **Gustav Tesche** b. July 13th 1877 in Wahlsdorf (near Berlin), d. East-Berlin ca. 1968. He had two daughters (Gerda and Hiltrud) and one known sister, so the name is lost.

In Jan. 2019 a record at findagrave listed Gustav Tesche (1885-1970) Memorial ID 196385784,  but it does not seem to help, does it?

Where should I search? Are there some resources online?

Comment: You need to narrow this question down -- 'ancestors' is too broad.  Do you have any sources you can link to for the information you have so far (there's a handy edit button under your question.) And the first step would be the parents of Gustav so I've edited your question with that focus,

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE! Your original phrasing asked for "German (or other) ancestors" - Do you have some reason to doubt that Gustav's ancestry was not German?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tesche looks like a German name but so far I have not been able to find anything.

Comment: We know Gustav Tesche family in Mexico City, my son and daughters names are Tesche, their great grand father was Gustav Tesche and came to Mexico and had one son name Ewald Tesche

Answer (score 2):

Right now (December 2016) there are no records online, but according to Ancestry’s [Janus project site](http://www.janus-projekt.de/partner/brandenburg) the following archives are Ancestry  partners and we can expect digitized resources in the future:

- Archiv des Landkreises Teltow-Fläming
- Archiv des Landkreises Dahme-Spreewald

Wahlsdorf belongs to the first district (Teltow-Fläming).

The parents of Gustav Tesche should be noted in his birth record.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but it seems that since the previous answer was written, Ancestry has made more digitized records available. There are baptism, marriage, and some death records available for the region you're interested in.

You'll need to brush up on your Kurrent (19th-century German cursive handwriting) paleography or find someone who can read it for you. You'll also want to familiarize yourself with German number and date formats ([one] thousand eight hundred seven and seventy, for example). Also, simple words like *Sohn*, *Tochter*, *geboren*, *wohnhaft*, as well as more specialized words that might appear on these official documents.

For example:

1. Ancestry has a marriage record for the following couple:

   - (word) (word) Friedrich Gustav Tesche, ... geboren am dreizehnten Juli des Jahres tausend achthundert sieben und siebzig [born on 13th July 1877] zu Wahlsdorf, (word) Jüterbog-Luckenwalde, wohnhaft in Berlin ... Sohn der L_(?) Friedrich Tesche und (word) (word) Friederika (name?) Kutscher, (word) wohnhaft in Wahlsdorf
   - Paula Margareta Golecki, ... geboren am sechs und zwanzig ten November des Jahres tausend achthundert zwei und achtzig [born on 26th November 1882] zu Berlin, wohnhaft in Berlin ... Tochter der (word) Franz Alexander Golecki und (word) (word) Elizabeth Harmina(?) Karolina geboren Newjahn, (word) wohnhaft in Berlin

   There's quite a lot more detail on the marriage record. I just wrote what I could read at first glance, and I've probably mistranscribed something so you'll want to examine the documents closely.
2. Ancestry has baptismal records for Paula Margarethe Golecki (parents Franz Alexander Golecki and Elisabeth Hermine Caroline Golecki), 26 Nov 1882 Berlin and Julia Wilhelmina Hiltrud Tesche (parents Friedrich Gustav Tesche and Paula Margarete Tesche), 28 Oct 1905 Berlin.
3. Ancestry also has a marriage record for a Friedrich Wilhelm Tesche to Johanne Friederike Kutscher, 8 Jul 1876 in Brandenburg state.

If these are your people and you haven't already found these records in the past 3.5 years, you might give it another try.

You'll want to remember the FAN club principle: friends/family, associates, neighbors. So any children/siblings/parents you find, you'll want to follow both forward and backward, to find siblings/cousins because those records might mention the people you're looking for.

You say you know your Gustav's sisters' names, so try to find their marriage records, which might list the parents and the sisters' birth dates. If you think they're the right ones, try to find their baptismal records, which will support or provide more information.

Sources

1. Ancestry.com. *Berlin, Germany, Marriages, 1874-1920* [database on-line]. Provo, UT, USA: Ancestry.com Operations, Inc., 2014.
   Original data: Heiratsregister der Berliner Standesämter 1874 - 1920.  Digital images. Landesarchiv, Berlin, Deutschland.
   Register Year or Type: 1904 (Zurückgeführtes Erstregister)
2. Ancestry.com. *Berlin, Germany, Births, 1874-1906* [database on-line]. Provo, UT, USA: Ancestry.com Operations, Inc., 2014.
   Original data: Geburtenregister der Berliner Standesämter (Bestände P Rep. 100 bis P Rep. 840) 1874–1906. Digital images. Landesarchiv Berlin, Germany.
   Landesarchiv Berlin; Berlin, Deutschland; *Personenstandsregister Geburtsregister*; Laufendenummer: 385 (Margarethe) and Laufendenummer: 920 (Hiltrud)
3. Ancestry.com. *Teltow-Fläming, Germany, Marriages, 1874-1923* [database on-line]. Provo, UT, USA: Ancestry.com Operations, Inc., 2016.
   Original data: Ehebücher, 1874-1923. Gemeindearchiv Blankenfelde Mahlow, Blankenfelde Mahlow, Deutschland.
   Ehebücher und Namensverzeichnisse, 1874-1923. Archiv des Landkreises Teltow-Fläming, Luckenwalde, Deutschland.
   Year Range: 1874 - 1900

Comment: Thanks a million! I just knew that Gustav married a Margarethe about whose family name I was unsure. Is there a direct path to these documents or only Ancestry provides access?

Comment: @unsure I found them through Ancestry, which I normally access at my local library, but during the COVID-19 closure, my library (or Ancestry) has made them accessible remotely with just a library card number. If you have a library card, you might check your local library. If you don't, check anyway; if your library offers access to Ancestry, it's possible you can sign up for a library card online.

Comment: But to answer your question another way, I will edit the answer to provide citations for the sources.